# Triggering a breakpoint while deleting memory C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

In my task I need to input some data about, let's say, depositor and then increase his amount of money by 15% but that`s not the point. The main problem is that it always "triggers a breakpoint" and transfers me to this page [image]

Function where I allocate memory:

```
void allocateMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words, const int max) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        szData[i] = new char* [words]; //how many words in every row
        for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
        {
            szData[i][j] = new char[max]; //maximum quantity of symbols in every word
        }
    }
}
```

Function where I assign some values:

```
void assignFirst(char*** szData, const int rows, const int max) { 

    char* s1 = new char[max];  
    char* s2 = new char[max];
    char* s3 = new char[max];
    char* s4 = new char[max];
    char* s5 = new char[max];

    cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s4 >> s5;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        szData[i][0] = s1;
        szData[i][1] = s2;
        szData[i][2] = s3;
        szData[i][3] = s4;
        szData[i][4] = s5;
    }
}
```

Function where I delete memory:

```
void freeMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
        {
            delete[] szData[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] szData[i];
    }

    delete[] szData;
}
```

How it looks in the console and where it breaks
[image]
How can I solve it?
P.S. cannot do it using `string` (must be an array of characters) or `vector` as it is the condition of my task I was given. And yes, I know that `new` is sort of outdated

Full code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std;

void allocateMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words, const int max);
void assignFirst(char*** szData, const int rows, const int max);
void print(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words);
void freeMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words);

void main() {
    const int rowCount = 2;
    const int wordCount = 5; //number of words in every row
    const int maxWordLength = 10; 

    char*** szData = new char** [rowCount];

    allocateMemory(szData, rowCount, wordCount, maxWordLength);

    assignFirst(szData, rowCount, maxWordLength);
    print(szData, rowCount, wordCount);

    freeMemory(szData, rowCount, wordCount);
}

void allocateMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words, const int max) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        szData[i] = new char* [words]; //how many words in every row
        for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
        {
            szData[i][j] = new char[max]; //maximum quantity of symbols in every word
        }
    }
}

void assignFirst(char*** szData, const int rows, const int max) { 

    char* s1 = new char[max];  
    char* s2 = new char[max];
    char* s3 = new char[max];
    char* s4 = new char[max];
    char* s5 = new char[max];

    cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s4 >> s5;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        szData[i][0] = s1;
        szData[i][1] = s2;
        szData[i][2] = s3;
        szData[i][3] = s4;
        szData[i][4] = s5;
    }
}

void print(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
        {
            if (j == 3) //change fourth element
            {
                double a = atoi(szData[i][3]); //convert fourth element into double
                a = a * 1.15; //add 15% to it
                cout << a << " ";
            }
            else
                cout << szData[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void freeMemory(char*** szData, const int rows, const int words) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
        {
            delete[] szData[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] szData[i];
    }

    delete[] szData;
}
```

Comment: It means your program has bug, you are corrupting the heap and this is detected when memory is freed.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but if you used standard C++ classes such as `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of trying to do manual memory allocation, you'd find it far easier to write bug free code.

Comment: OK, so it's not your choice, but you know about [this](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)? I have to question how you are being taught. It's bad enough in C but you are allegedly being taught C++

Comment: yes, I've been told this multiple times, unfortunately. Didn't know about that link though. I also thought that I can't just learn `vector` and all that until I learn how to use 'dynamic' stuff manually or something like that

Comment: The dynamic stuff is hard. It's common sense that you should learn the easy stuff first, programming is hard enough as it is. But for some reason many teachers prefer to follow the historical development of the C++ language, instead of common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is here

```
void assignFirst(char*** szData, const int rows, const int max) { 

    char* s1 = new char[max];  
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        szData[i][0] = s1;
        ...
    }
}
```

You assign the same pointer to multiple entries of `szData`. But here

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < words; j++)
    {
        delete[] szData[i][j];
    }
}
```

you delete those pointers as if they are all separately allocated.

In other words you are deleteing the same pointer multiple times, and that explains the error.

Comment: I removed that nested loop in a function that freeing memory and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @ovvvol OK, but now you probably have a memory leak. That's the problem with manual memory management, delete too much and your program crashes, delete too little and you have a memory leak. Probably the correct solution would be to change the first loop so that you don't assign the same pointer to multiple entries in your arrray in the first place.